# Renesas compilation error symbol _FunctionName multiply defined

Tags: c, compiler-errors, embedded

I'm trying to compile on RENESAS and i get the following error :
 symbol _FunctionName multiply defined 
where it's declared in one of my .h file and defined in one of my c files and the other one in an integrated library (i have no access on it) i tried removing the declaration and leave only the definition , but this didn't work also , i got the same error. 
Is there any compiler command to ignore this ??

Answer (score 1):

You tried to solve it the wrong way around. There must be exactly one definition of each symbol. So if there is already one in the library, remove the *definition* from your code. Your declaration in the `.h` file then helps you to access that variable.

All of this supposes that your declaration reflects well the type and intention of the library variable. If not, just change the name of your variable to avoid the conflict with the library.

Answer (score 1):

What you describe is a *linker* error rather than a *compiler* error.  It is not clear what you mean by a *"integrated library"*, but when you link a static-link library, only object code necessary to resolve unresolved symbols *after* all separately compiled object code is explicitly linked, so normally it is possible to override a library definition simply by defining the symbol in your own code.

However if the library is not sufficiently granular and a single object module in the library contains multiple public symbols, if you reference one, all others are linked.  So in this case if `_FunctionName` is defined in the same module as `_AnotherFunctionName`, and you reference `_AnotherFunctionName` then `_FunctionName` will also be linked and will clash with your override.

Ideally libraries should be modularised such that any single module defines only one public interface - that way you can override any single interface.

One possible solution is to determine what other symbols share the same object module as `_FunctionName`, and then define those too; but that may be error prone and complex to do.

The simple solution is not to use the same name as that used in the library, but that will not allow your function to replace any calls made to it from within the library which may be your intent.